# How to change a NSDate's day by adding hours?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I have an app firing off UILocalNotifications every hour, which will stop at the time the user selected in a date picker. I pre set 23 local notifications by adding hour components by one. The problem is, when the hour passes 12:00 AM the day stays in the same day and does not change. How do I have the NSDate change the day when the hour reaches 12:00 AM? Thanks for the help.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate]; 

NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:0];

//date chosen from the picker with seconds = 0 i.e., final alarm
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];


//setting the final alarm

UILocalNotification *finalAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (finalAlarm) {
    finalAlarm.fireDate = itemDate;
    finalAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    finalAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    finalAlarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    finalAlarm.alertBody = @"Test message...";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:finalAlarm];
}  

//Formatting original date to isolate the current hour
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];

//Formatting original date to isolate the current minute
NSDateFormatter *minuteFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[minuteFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"]; 

//creating a NSDateFormatter for readability
NSDateFormatter *yearMonthDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[yearMonthDay setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];


//isolate current date/hour/minute
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *currentHour = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSString *currentMinute = [minuteFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];


NSString *currentForamttedDate = [yearMonthDay stringFromDate:currentDate];
NSLog(@"Current Date: %@",currentForamttedDate); 

//current hour int
int currentHourInt = [currentHour intValue];

//current minute int
int currentMinuteInt = [currentMinute intValue];    


//current hour plus 1
int firstAlarmHour = currentHourInt + 1;

//creating the first alarm
NSDateComponents *firstAlarm = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];

[firstAlarm setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[firstAlarm setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[firstAlarm setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[firstAlarm setHour:firstAlarmHour];
[firstAlarm setMinute:currentMinuteInt];
[firstAlarm setSecond:0];

//creating a date from the components
NSDate *firstAlarmDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstAlarm];

//setting the first alarm
[self scheduleNotificationForDate: firstAlarmDate finalAlarm:itemDate];

-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate: (NSDate*)date finalAlarm: (NSDate *)finalAlarmDate {


NSComparisonResult result = [finalAlarmDate compare:date];

    if (alarm) {
        alarm.fireDate = date;
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        alarm.alertBody = @"Test message...";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Improved:

Create a date component for a single hour, then get the calendar to add that component to your previously calculated (initial) fire date:

```
NSDateComponents *hourComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
hourComponent.hour = 1;

dateToBeIncremented = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:hourComponent toDate:dateToBeIncremented options:0];
```

Original (which have issues with time zones):

How about using the date components to organise the date for the first notification, then using `NSDate` `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` to calculate the subsequent dates by adding a days worth of seconds.

A better alternative may be to create a debate component for a single hour. Once you have the first fire date, then use the hour date component to generate the next fire date, then use that one to generate the next. This should deal with more time zone related issues than the above method.

Comment: I'll look it up and try it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It worked. Also, it was a much more efficient way of setting the alarm. Thanks!

Comment: This is **NOT** how you do time calculations! Time's a bitch, and this method may work 99% of the time, but it will definitely break at some point!

Comment: @JustSid is correct, you do need to be careful. The above method will sooner or later run into an issue when time zone changes for example.

Comment: Please offer advice if you down vote, I'm interested to know better solutions for per calculated relative dates too.

Comment: The computation above is totally ok. NSDate's internal representation is timezone agnostic. You get time zone/daylight adjusted values when you print the time as a string or view it in the debugger (which is essentially the same).